# lapply'ing a for loop returns NULL

Tags: r, list, for-loop, gsub, lapply

I have a simple list

```
list1<-data.frame(col1=c("text;aaa","text", "text;aaa","text"), col2=1:4)
list2<- data.frame(col1=c("text;aaa","text", "text;aaa","text", "text", "text"), col2=1:6)
mylist<-list(list1,list2)
```

I now want to sub all text after **;** with a for loop, like this

```
list.2 <- lapply(mylist, function(x){
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    if(grepl(";",x[i,1]) == T){
      x[i,1] <- gsub(";.*", "", x[i,1])
    } else x[i,1] <- x[i,1]
  }
}  )
```

But the output is `NULL`

```
list.2
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `x` in the function within `lapply` otherwise nothing will get returned:

```
lapply(mylist, function(x){
  for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
    if(grepl(";",x[i,1])){
      x[i,1] <- gsub(";.*", "", x[i,1])
    } else x[i,1] <- x[i,1]
  }
  #return the x you modified previously
  x
})
```

Output:

```
[[1]]
  col1 col2
1 text    1
2 text    2
3 text    3
4 text    4

[[2]]
  col1 col2
1 text    1
2 text    2
3 text    3
4 text    4
5 text    5
6 text    6
```

Also, as a side note, you do not need `grepl(";",x[i,1]) == T` but only `grepl(";",x[i,1])` since `grepl` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` anyway (so you do not need to test for `TRUE==TRUE`).

Comment: Thanks. That was an embarrassing mistake.

Comment: @USER_1 You are very welcome. No mistake is embarrassing btw, even experienced users / developers need some help sometimes (especially after long hours decoding). So, no need to feel embarrassed :)